# How to use an IN Clause with a user defined list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query:

```
Select sum(net_sales)
from Sales_tb
where Store_number in (@list)
```

Obviously I can't use a parameter in the `in` clause.

I need to pass the @list through a vb.net program.

An example would be: `'1,5,6'`

How can I accomplish this since the parameter isn't really an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're passing a `VARCHAR`, comma-delimited list, then you need a string splitter. Aaron Bertrand wrote an [article](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) comparing the different methods to split a string.

```
SELECT SUM(net_sales)
FROM Sales_tb
WHERE 
    Store_number IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitStrings(@list, ','))
```

Comment: This is fantastic!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pass a table, not a string. SQL Server 2008 has Table-valued Parameters.

[Table-Valued Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Use Table-Valued Parameters (Database Engine)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/bb510489.aspx)